# Simple finding specific information using Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to find out what is the id of the subsidiary of movies where Iron Man (alias for Tony Stark) is one of the actor roles....

My Xml

this is some correct `//Disney/Subsidiaries/Subsidiary[@id='MarvelStudios']/Movie` and more, but i tried ( `//Disney/Subsidiaries/Subsidiary[@id='MarvelStudios']/Movie[@lang='Iron Man']/Name`) but it wont work

```
<Movie>
    <Name lang="en">Iron Man</Name>
    <Year>2008</Year>
    <ScreenTime unit="minutes">126</ScreenTime>
    <Cast>
      <Role name="Tony Stark" alias="Iron Man" actor="RobertDowneyJr" />
      <Role name="Rhodey" actor="TerrenceHoward" />
      <Role name="Pepper Potts" actor="GwynethPaltrow" />
    </Cast>
  </Movie>
```

I need it return 1 line, where the movie contains iron man in

Comment: Firstly, you've said you want it to return "1 line", but (a) you haven't said what that line should be, and (b) XPath expressions return nodes, not lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your xpath

```
//Disney/Subsidiaries/Subsidiary[@id='MarvelStudios']/Movie[Name='Iron Man'][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fetch the name of the movie where the cast is tony stark you may try this Xpath

```
"//Cast/Role[@name='Tony Stark']/ancestor::Name"
```

And then use getText() method on the webElement you find using the locator. You would be able to get the Movie name.